# How Azure WebJob runs application?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I wondering how Azure Webjob works.
If I put any .exe file to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\triggered\sample>`
with file Settings.job

```
{
   "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
}
```

then that .exe file will be executed every minute? How Azure know which file should trigger? Does he just look for any exe file?

Comment: In my opinion, webjob is similar with azure function, I use webjob to do some tasks which need to be triggered or run continuously. And according to [ms document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#acceptablefiles),  webjob needs to upload an executing file(script or program), it means webjob just need to analyze the file format(exe,jar,bat...) and provide correct container to deploy them. Actually, I never put several executing files into one zip file to test which one will be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create 3 `.bat` file to test.

**When kudu executes webjob, it will find the first matching file type (`.bat`, `.exe`, `.py` and so on) according to the naming rules, and run it.**

## My Test Steps

1. Create `webjob{num}.bat` file with below script.

   ```
   @ECHO OFF
   echo Hello World webjob{num}!
   ```
2. I create webjob on portal by upload `.bat` file. Then drop and paste another two `.bat` file to the path of `webjob1` folder.

[image]

3. I check the log, I found that when kudu executes webjob, it will only run one file. After testing, the first file will be run according to the naming rules.

[image]